# PACT and selenium

Tags: selenium, pact

I'm a automation engineer and I was wondering if pact could help us in any way to increase test coverage

I'm new to PACT, but I was thinking if it could be possible to generate a pact file with existing selenium web tests?

It is that the contract can be used in different ways. 2 different web apps using the **same** API, can use it in a **different** way.

Our web app uses a certain set of API and these also results in http get, post, etc. So in principle a pact file could be generated in that way.

It by-passes the original intention of PACT, where consumer and producer devs work together on contract refinement.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

This would not be a good fit for the Pact tool. Let me copy/paste a section of the Best Practices information below.

> #### Use `Pact` for isolated (unit) tests
>
> - as a mock (calls to mocks are verified after a test) not a stub (calls to stubs are not verified). Using `Pact` as a stub defeats the purpose of using `Pacts`.
> - for *isolated tests* (ie. unit tests) of the class(es) that will be responsible for making the HTTP calls from your `Consumer` application to your `Provider` application, not for integrated tests of your entire consumer codebase.
> - *carefully*, for any sort of functional or integrated tests within your consumer codebase.
>
> **Why?**
>
> If you use `Pact` with exact matching for integrated tests, you will drive yourself nuts. You will have very brittle `Consumer` tests, as `Pact` checks every outgoing path, JSON node, query param and header. You will also end up with a cartesian explosion of interactions that need to be verified on the `Provider` side. This will increase the amount of time you spend getting your `Provider` tests to pass, without usefully increasing the amount of test coverage.

Pact is a contract testing tool, rather than a general purpose stubbing or mocking tool. The best use of Pact involves testing as little of the code that does not concern itself with the HTTP request/response as possible. This will keep your tests fast and maintainable.